# Select values that are within a certain range but exclude the values that determine the range in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a SQLite local database, I have a 2 column-table, one containing values, and one containing categories. I want to update the categories of certain rows based on the following selection:

- select the rows that are in a certain category
- determine the values for those rows.
- select the rows that have values within a certain range of the values of the already selected rows.
- update the rows that are within the second selection, but exclude those that are in the first selection.

The statement that I have now (that does not work) is as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET category = '3' WHERE 
(
value BETWEEN 
(
((SELECT value FROM table WHERE category = '2') +4) 
AND 
((SELECT value FROM table WHERE category = '2') -4)
EXCEPT SELECT value FROM table WHERE category = '2'
)
... (further constraints)
)
```

This runs without error, but does not actually appear to select anything, as nothing is updated. What is the correct way to get this update to work?

EDIT: as requested an example with tables:

| rowid | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | 30 | 2 |
| 3 | 40 | 2 |
| 4 | 70 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 19 | 1 |
| 7 | 26 | 1 |
| 8 | 42 | 1 |
| 9 | 49 | 1 |
| 10 | 52 | 1 |
| 11 | 71 | 1 |
| 12 | 90 | 1 |

I want the values of the rows that are currently in category 1, to be placed in category 3, based on a range of 4 around the values of the rows that are in category 2. So in this case any row that has category = 1, that has a value of either 16-24, 26-34, 36-44 or 66-74.

| rowid | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | 30 | 2 |
| 3 | 40 | 2 |
| 4 | 70 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 19 | 3 |
| 7 | 26 | 3 |
| 8 | 42 | 3 |
| 9 | 49 | 1 |
| 10 | 52 | 1 |
| 11 | 71 | 3 |
| 12 | 90 | 1 |

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired results. This is very confusing as it's written.

Comment: @JNevill I have added an example using sample data. I hope this helps

Comment: Do you want to update only the rows with Category = 1?

Comment: @forpas Yes, I want to only update the rows with category =1, as there are cases in which I'd want to update to category =3 instead, and I don't want category 2 to change.

Comment: Your sample data contains only Categories 1 and 2 and i your question you mention: *...to be placed in category 2 (or any other category)...*. Clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas I have changed the question to use a 3rd category, I hope this is a little clearer. (and removed the picture which was evidently only confusing people)

Comment: … select value+1 (…) select value-1 …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Category = 3
WHERE Category = 1
  AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tablename t
        WHERE t.Category = 2
          AND tablename.Value BETWEEN t.Value - 4 AND t.Value + 4
      );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=63d69bcc2c881755c51de41082aea0e3).

Comment: Hi Forpas, thanks, this is really really close to what I want. The problem I now have is that it applies to values that during running come to be within the constraints of the second ```Select```. Only a problem when the category to set to is the same as the category based on which the selection is made. Coincidentally that doesn't happen with my sample data, so I have accepted your answer, but it is a problem I run into with my actual dataset. Is there a way to make it run so that does not happen?

Comment: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3be819013559f5778365f1d8bb3bc514) I adjusted the demo to be closer to my actual dataset, wheren this problem presents (category in row 13 changes though it should not.)

Comment: @MappingThePast My answer is about the question as you posted it. For this new requirement you should ask a new question

Comment: New question asked. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165599/update-rows-based-on-range-around-values-without-changing-rows-that-are-not-init)