# Update rows based on range around values without changing rows that are not initially within range

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

In a local SQLite (vs 3.29.0) database, there is a table with 3 columns (excluding the rowID). Two contain values, and one contains categories. I want to update the category based on a range around the values of one specific category. It needs to be possible that the category that is `SET` is the same category as the one that determines the range.

Example:

| id | Value | Value2 | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | 30 | 30 | 2 |
| 3 | 40 | 40 | 2 |
| 4 | 70 | 70 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 19 | 19 | 1 |
| 7 | 26 | 26 | 1 |
| 8 | 42 | 42 | 1 |
| 9 | 49 | 49 | 1 |
| 10 | 52 | 52 | 1 |
| 11 | 71 | 71 | 1 |
| 12 | 90 | 90 | 1 |
| 13 | 17 | 17 | 1 |

I want rows to be changed to category 2, based on a range of 4 around `value` and a range of 2 around `value2`. This should change only rows 6, 9 and 11:

| id | Value | Value2 | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | 30 | 30 | 2 |
| 3 | 40 | 40 | 2 |
| 4 | 70 | 70 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 19 | 19 | 2 |
| 7 | 26 | 26 | 1 |
| 8 | 42 | 42 | 2 |
| 9 | 49 | 49 | 1 |
| 10 | 52 | 52 | 1 |
| 11 | 71 | 71 | 2 |
| 12 | 90 | 90 | 1 |
| 13 | 17 | 17 | 1 |

My current SQL statement is:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Category = 2
WHERE (Category != 2
  AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM tablename t
        WHERE t.Category = 2
          AND tablename.Value BETWEEN t.Value - 4 AND t.Value + 4
          AND tablename.Value2 BETWEEN t.Value2 -2 AND t.Value2 +2)
          );
```

of which the result is:

| id | Value | Value2 | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 20 | 2 |
| 2 | 30 | 30 | 2 |
| 3 | 40 | 40 | 2 |
| 4 | 70 | 70 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 19 | 19 | 2 |
| 7 | 26 | 26 | 1 |
| 8 | 42 | 42 | 2 |
| 9 | 49 | 49 | 1 |
| 10 | 52 | 52 | 1 |
| 11 | 71 | 71 | 2 |
| 12 | 90 | 90 | 1 |
| 13 | 17 | 17 | 2 |

What appears to be happening is that due to row 6 changing to category 2, row 13 is now within range of the values of a row that is in category 2, and therefore is also assigned category 2. How do I change the statement so that the `SET` is only applied to the values that were within range initially?

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a153b4564cc733ce64b49e5fded5ef64) for the example.

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: version 3.29.0 (now also included in main text).

Comment: If you can upgrade to (at least) 3.33.0 you can use the code in my answer.

Comment: I'm looking into whether this is possible, but suspect it is not. I am in a pre-determined environment (QGIS 3.16, with python 3.7, which has a pre-installed version of sqlite3) that I cannot simply change, without affecting the end-users of my QGIS-plugin (who would have to do a manual install of the new version rather than the plugin being ready to use- and the end users are not necessarily computer savvy, so I'm trying to avoid that).

Comment: Check my 2nd query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the join-like `UPDATE...FROM` syntax to perform a self join in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET Category = t2.Category
FROM tablename AS t2 
WHERE t2.Category = 2
  AND t1.Category <> t2.Category
  AND t1.Value BETWEEN t2.Value - 4 AND t2.Value + 4
  AND t1.Value2 BETWEEN t2.Value2 - 2 AND t2.Value2 + 2;
```

For previous versions of SQLite, first create a temporary table with all the rows of the table with `Category = 2`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS 
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Category = 2;
```

and then update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET Category = 2
WHERE Category <> 2
  AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM t
        WHERE tablename.Value BETWEEN t.Value - 4 AND t.Value + 4
          AND tablename.Value2 BETWEEN t.Value2 -2 AND t.Value2 + 2
      );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b4eba8a57e6489635566e429b08b4e84).